# C++: When should i use _disable() _enable()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intrinsics

Visual Studio allows instructs to clear the processors interrupt flag via _disable or _enable (see link). When, it is recommended to use such tools. Especally, in view of performance.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzkfha43.aspx

Comment: I'm not a kernel mode driver developer. What is kernel mode?

Comment: Missing a minimal understanding of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_disable()` and `_enable()` are used, respectively, to disable and enable interrupts.

[Read more about interrupts here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt)

If you're a C++ beginner, you probably don't need this, except if your goal is to write an operating system kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, never. Just forget it exists. :)